# How to enable HTTP connection in gcloud? - connection refused

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform

I tried to enable http connection to gcloud project and when I'm trying to reach an html file on the server, it returns a tcp reset packet (as I saw in wireshark), and on the browser I see the following:

[image: connection refused]

my firewall rules are:

[image: firewall rules]

here are my VM Instace details (without the ssh key)
[image: vpc settings]
[image: vpc settings continue]
I even checked that ping is working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created instance in default vpc subnet? Can you add your vm advance settings screenshot?

Comment: added to your request @JohnRiddick

Comment: are you able to ssh into the instance? can you install tcpdump and check if traffic is coming to your instance or not?

Comment: I've just checked and I'm able to access the webpage "http://35.188.142.202/". Could you confirm if you did change anything?

Comment: Actually, I'm not working alone, My colleague handled it.